# Add NMS layer to onnx model and test it

Tags: pytorch, onnx, onnxruntime

I have an onnx format of complex-yolo pretrained model which has been created by this code:

```
torch.onnx.export(model,               # model being run
                input_imgs,                         # model input (or a tuple for multiple inputs)
                "./Complex_yolo_300.onnx",   # where to save the model (can be a file or file-like object)
                export_params=True,        # store the trained parameter weights inside the model file
                opset_version=11,          # the ONNX version to export the model to
                do_constant_folding=True,  # whether to execute constant folding for optimization
                input_names = ['input'],   # the model's input names
                output_names = ['output'], # the model's output names
               )
```

Now I want to load this model, add NMS layer to it and save it.I added the NMS layer by (the code is adopted from [here][1]:):

```
onnx_model = onnx.load("Complex_yolo_epoch_300.onnx")
    onnx.checker.check_model(onnx_model)
    onnx_model_with_nms_path = "Complex_yolo_epoch_300_with_nms.onnx"

    graph = onnx_model.graph

    # operation to transpose bbox before pass to NMS node
    transpose_scores_node = onnx.helper.make_node(
    'Transpose', 
    inputs=['output'], 
    outputs=['scores_transposed'],
    perm=(0, 2, 1))
    graph.node.append(transpose_scores_node)

    # make constant tensors for nms
    score_threshold = onnx.helper.make_tensor("score_threshold", TensorProto.FLOAT, [1], [0.25])
    iou_threshold = onnx.helper.make_tensor("iou_threshold", TensorProto.FLOAT, [1], [0.45])
    max_output_boxes_per_class = onnx.helper.make_tensor("max_output_boxes_per_class", TensorProto.INT64, [1], [200])

    # create the NMS node
    inputs=["output",'scores_transposed' , 'max_output_boxes_per_class', 'iou_threshold', 'score_threshold',]
    # inputs=['onnx::Concat_458', 'onnx::Concat_459', 'max_output_boxes_per_class', 'iou_threshold', 'score_threshold',]
    outputs = ["selected_indices"]
    nms_node = onnx.helper.make_node(
        'NonMaxSuppression',
        inputs,
        outputs=["selected_indices"],
        center_point_box=1, 
    )

    # add NMS node to the list of graph nodes
    graph.node.append(nms_node)

    # append to the output (now the outputs would be scores, bboxes, selected_indices)
    output_value_info = onnx.helper.make_tensor_value_info("selected_indices", TensorProto.INT64, shape=["num_results",3])
    graph.output.append(output_value_info)

    
    # add to initializers - without this, onnx will not know where these came from, and complain that 
    # they're neither outputs of other nodes, nor inputs. As initializers, however, they are treated 
    # as constants needed for the NMS op
    graph.initializer.append(score_threshold)
    graph.initializer.append(iou_threshold)
    graph.initializer.append(max_output_boxes_per_class)

    # check that it works and re-save
    onnx.checker.check_model(onnx_model)
    onnx.save(onnx_model, onnx_model_with_nms_path)
```

By running this the model is created successfully, however when I want to test it on a sample image it gives me an error:

```
ort_session = onnxruntime.InferenceSession("Complex_yolo_epoch_300_with_nms.onnx")

    test_dataloader = create_test_dataloader(configs)
    with torch.no_grad():
        for batch_idx, (img_paths, imgs_bev) in enumerate(test_dataloader):
            input_imgs = imgs_bev.to(device).float()
            # compute ONNX Runtime output prediction
            ort_inputs = {ort_session.get_inputs()[0].name: to_numpy(input_imgs)}
            ort_outs = ort_session.run(None, ort_inputs)
```

The error:

```
ort_outs = ort_session.run(None, ort_inputs)
  File "/home/azar/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_1_1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/onnxruntime/capi/onnxruntime_inference_collection.py", line 220, in run
    return self._sess.run(output_names, input_feed, run_options)
onnxruntime.capi.onnxruntime_pybind11_state.Fail: [ONNXRuntimeError] : 1 : FAIL : Non-zero status code returned while running NonMaxSuppression node. Name:'' Status Message: non_max_suppression.cc:92 PrepareCompute The most inner dimension in boxes must have 4 data.
```

I know that the shape of `output` should be `[num_batches, spatial_dimension, 4]` and in my case it is  `[num_batches, spatial_dimension, 10]`, but I do not know how can I pass only the first 4 to NMS layer.
How can I create a node that is exactly the same as `output` but with a different shaped

Comment: Do you have access to the `pytorch` model source code? I've found it much easier to write a wrapper class for the original model, append or prepend the desired functionality in `forward`, and export the new model directly. If not, maybe try exporting only the `Split` operation, see how it looks in resulting `ONNX` graph? Then you could manually insert it between model output and NMS.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I change `forward`, it means that I need to train it again, right? I do have access to `pytorch` source code but I wanted to find a way to add NMS layer without the need of training the model again.

Comment: You don't! You can just write a version of your `nn.Module` with the `torchvision` NMS call at the end of your forward pass, use `load_state_dict` to load the weights of your trained model, and export it to ONNX.